# DirectoryIterator scan to exclude '.' and '..' directories still including them?

Tags: php, spl, recursive-datastructures

In the script below, I'm trying to copy the folders that exist in the $base directory over to the $target directory. However, in my initial echo test, its returning the . and .. directories even though I'm trying to handle that exception in the conditional.

What am I missing?

```
    $base = dirname(__FILE__).'/themes/';
    $target = dirname( STYLESHEETPATH );
    $directory_folders = new DirectoryIterator($base); 
    foreach ($directory_folders as $folder) 
    {
         if ($folder->getPath() !== '.' && $folder->getPath() !=='..' ) 
         {
            echo '<br>getPathname: '. $folder->getPathname();
            //copy($folder->getPathname(), $target);
         }
    }die;
```

However, and this makes no sense to me, if I change the conditional to...

```
         if (!is_dir($folder) && $folder->getPath() !== '.' && $folder->getPath() !=='..' )
```

It returns the correct folders inside of $base. What?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`DirectoryIterator::getPath()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getpath.php) returns the **full path** to the directory -- and not only the last part of it.

If you only want the last portion of that path, you should probably use [**`SplFileInfo::getBasename()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getbasename.php) in your condition.

Or, for your specific test, you might want to take a look at the [**`DirectoryIterator::isDot()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isdot.php) method *(quoting)* :

> Determine if current
> `DirectoryIterator` item is `'.'` or
> `'..'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DirectoryIterator::isDot` instead:

```
if (!$folder->isDot())
```